# Http Post on Android: Server Request and Response

Tags: android, http-post, httprequest

I am trying to send information to a server from an android phone.

When the server receives the information it sends back a 1 or a 0 to signify pass or fail. Server-side everything is fine because there in another app for iOS that does the same thing, but it works. Also the sever sends an email anytime it receives a request.

My problem is that it does not seem like the app is contacting the server. When I run the app no response is given back and no email is sent once the Http Post code is executed.

I have the Http Post code below, thank you for any help you can give .

```
    public void send()
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(site);

            try {
                 // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dateOfEventStart", startYear + "-" + startMonth + "-" + startDay));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dateOfEventEnd", endYear + "-" + endMonth + "-" + endDay));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locationType", locType));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locationZipCode", location));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eventType", type));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("groundSurface", groundType));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numberOfGuests", numGuests + ""));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("seatingArrangments", arrangement));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("accessoriesTables",stuff));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("estimatedArea", tent));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("estimatedRoomToSpare", spared));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contactName", nameA));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contactPhone", phoneA));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contactEmail", addressA));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contactComments", comment));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("isInternational", isInternational + ""));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                responseString = response.toString();


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }

        }
```

site is variable that was declared earlier on. It is a string that contains location of the form receiver

also below  is the information I was given about the server

> You will send it a “POST” request with (most likely) a “content-type” of “application/x-www-form-urlencoded”.
>
> The content of the “POST” will be a String that is formatted like a website URL’s “Query >String”. (That’s the stuff after the question mark if you’re not familiar with them.)
>
> In this string, there are keys and values connected by an equal sign. Key/Value pairs are >separated by ampersands (&’s).
>
> Here is an example of a string I used in ASP to test the service if it helps (with >carriage returns added for readability):
>
> strContent = "dateOfEventStart=2011-09-24
>
> &dateOfEventEnd=2011-09-26
>
> &locationType=" & Server.URLEncode("Residential") & "
>
> &locationZipCode=38016
>
> &eventType=" & Server.URLEncode("Corporate Event") & "
>
> &eventTypeSecondary=
>
> &groundSurface=" & Server.URLEncode("Gravel (over dirt)") & "
>
> &groundSurfaceSecondary=
>
> &numberOfGuests=90
>
> &seatingArrangements=" & Server.URLEncode("Round tables of 6 guests") & "
>
> &accessoriesTables=" & Server.URLEncode("Buffet,Cake,Gift,Beverage Station") & "
>
> &accessoriesEntertainment=
>
> &estimatedArea=" & Server.URLEncode("1200 sq ft") & "
>
> &estimatedTentSize=" & Server.URLEncode("30 ft x 40 ft or 20 ft x 60 ft") & "
>
> &estimatedRoomToSpare=" & Server.URLEncode("0 sq ft or 0 sq ft") & "
>
> &contactName=" & Server.URLEncode("Jonathan Chan") & "
>
> &contactPhone=9011234567
>
> &contactEmail=" & Server.URLEncode("jchan@lunaweb.com") & "
>
> &contactComments=" & Server.URLEncode("This is a long comment.")
>
> In my ASP example, you may have noticed “Server.URLEncode” surrounding Strings. This is >so certain characters that could mess up the data gets encoded into % hexadecimal ASCII >values. For example, if someone enters “I love cheese & cake” as his comment, the program >will think that the ampersand is denoting a new Key/Value pair. If we encode the URL, it >will look like “I%20love%20cheese%20%26%20cake”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See what are the errors in the logcat file
2. Check if you have included the Internet Permission in your manifest file.

Comment: Ok I checked the permissions, and the Internet permission was not there and I added. It now communicates with the server, but the form isn't working still. It receives the string, but does not seem to process it

Answer (score 0):

never do this

```
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Look here to see how to do it right: http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html